# Unable to define push_back in vectors

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, data-structures, c++14

Here I had defined the push_back an was using it in my code but don't know after doing this below task.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

#define pb push_back
vector<int> v[1001];
```

Here is the below error of this

```
prog.cpp:4:12: error: request for member ‘push_back’ in ‘v’, which is of non-class type ‘std::vector<int> [1001]’
 #define pb push_back
```

Comment: As a tip, use an IDE/editor which can help you autocomplete stuff like push_back instead of using defines. Maintaining such a code will become a nightmare down the line.

Comment: Just wait until `std::pb` is added to the library in C++ 27.

Comment: `pb` -- It's the same crazy macro used [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61435548/codeforces-compiler-showing-weird-symbols)

Comment: [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h/31816096) and [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/364696)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie -- Oh, that link is gooood...

Answer (score 0):

`vector<int> v[1001];` is not a vector, it's an array of vectors. I'm guessing you meant this

```
vector<int> v;
```

which is a vector `v` of zero size. You can then increase the size by using `push_back`. But it's possible that you meant this

```
vector<int> v(1001);
```

which is a vector `v` of size 1001. You can also increase the size of this vector by using push_back, but since it's already has a size of 1001 I'm not sure you would want to.

Without seeing more code it's hard to be sure.

And why the macro? `#define pb push_back`, what is the point of that? Please let me know.

Comment: But John, everyone else in the cargo cult uses it! Hey, You want some Kool-Aid?

Comment: #define pb push_back is used to save time .No worries thanks got it

Comment: @EngineerGraduate - Save time? You got an error that you couldn't make heads or tails of because it was obfuscated by the macro. How much time did it save you exactly?

Comment: It's used in competitive programming usually